# Sails.js Nested Folders For Controllers, Models, and Views

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Lets say I have an application that might have different sections and I want to organize my controllers in the following way:

```
api
  - controllers
    - DisciplineTracker
       - actionsController.js
    - SomeOtherAppSection
       - someOtherController.js
  - models
    - DisciplineTracker
      - Action.js
```

The above is actually what the sails generator creates when entering:

```
sails generate controller disciplineTracker/action
```

In the route file how would I load up actionsController.js in the DisciplineTracker folder? Currently when I try something like:

```
'get /discipline-tracker/actions': {
    controller: 'DisciplineTracker/ActionsController',
    action: 'index'
}
```

I get:

```
error: disciplinetracker/actions.index :: Ignoring attempt to bind route (/discipline-tracker/actions) to unknown controller.action.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

Edit 1: Just In Case

Yes, the index action exists inside the actionsController.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand the confusion here since your `sails generate controller disciplineTracker/action` seems to do something useful, when in fact it should probably just output an error because nested controllers are not supported in Sails at this time.  So the short answer is, you can't do this.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Update--nested controllers are supported in the latest dev build of Sails.  Not models yet, though.